# Calculate rank on a scale of 1-5 on a percentage series

Tags: excel

I am a newbie in ms excel and have to calculate performance on a scale of 1-5 whereas I have been given a final score of 50 candidates in % like below.

```
124.48%
124.35%
122.20%
120.17%
118.61%
116.25%
115.01%
114.66%
111.32%
111.16%
110.39%
109.77%
108.99%
108.79%
108.07%
107.21%
104.83%
103.97%
103.41%
103.00%
102.83%
102.75%
101.50%
101.29%
101.18%
101.09%
101.05%
99.97%
```

How am i suppose to rate them between a rating of 1-5. I believe that I have to set a bench mark for average performance. I have become clueless this moment of time. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the percentiles of it so `=PERCENTILE(A1:A50,0.2)` would give you the 20th percentile then

Lets assume that the data is in `A1:A50`. In B1 we could find the 20%ile value using `=PERCENTILE(A1:A50,0.2)` then in each cell of `C1:C50` you could put a formula of `=if(A1

Then rinse and repeat for 0.4 (40%ile) and so on up to the top

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PERCENTILE` function in an array formula and get the result in one go, e.g. with data in A2:A29 try this array formula in B2

`=MATCH(A2,PERCENTILE(A$2:A$29,{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down